# Instance member 'x' can't be accessed in an initializer - Flutter / Dart / General Programming Question

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, initialization

Pretty new to programming and very new to dart/flutter.

The properties of an object of one class are needed to construct an object of another class. I try constructing to the object of the independent class first and defining the property, then follow by constructing an object of the second class and passing it's constructor the property from first class as parameter. I get the following error,

Error Message: Instance member 'x' can't be accessed in an initializer

EDIT: typo in 3rd line of code has been changed

```
Example:

    void main(){
      Class1 instanceOfClass1 = Class1(property_A: 10);
      Class2 instanceOfClass2 = Class2(property_B: instanceOfClass1.property_A)
    }
    
    class Class1 {
      var property_A;
      
      Class1({required this.property_A});
    }
    
    class Class2 {
      var property_B;
      
      Class2({required this.property_B});
    }
```

Comment: Just wondering if anyone can help explain whats happening here and any possible solutions or alternative methods for constructing an object of one class based off of the properties of an object of another class.

Answer (score 0):

`property_A` is not a static variable hence it can't be accessed with `Class1.property_A`

It is rather a field in an object/instance of `Class1`

Access it with `instanceOfClass1.property_A` instead. Like so:

```
 void main(){
      Class1 instanceOfClass1 = Class1(property_A: 10);
      Class2 instanceOfClass2 = Class2(property_B: instanceOfClass1.property_A);
    }
    
    class Class1 {
      var property_A;
      
      Class1({required this.property_A});
    }
    
    class Class2 {
      var property_B;
      
      Class2({required this.property_B});
    }
```

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. I meant to access 'instanceOfClass1.property_A' and not 'Class1.property_A'. I still get the error when trying to access 'instanceOfClass1.property_A'

Comment: Hey @XavierRenegadeAngel, what error do you get when you use `instanceOfClass1.property_A`?

Comment: Instance member 'x' can't be accessed in an initializer